# Transitive library dependency in Premake?

Tags: premake

I have a problem with linking libraries correctly to my projects using gmake and premake5 (On Linux, elementaryOS). I'm using premake to generate the makefiles. I have 3 projects in my workspace: glfw (the library I want to be linked to), Celer (The library I wanted to start working on, it should be linked with glfw) and Sandbox (my testing app). The linking between Sandbox and Celer works without any problems, but when I try to link Celer and glfw, undefined refrences occur and I just can't figure out why.

```
==== Building glfw (debug) ====
==== Building Celer (debug) ====
==== Building Sandbox (debug) ====
Linking Sandbox
../../bin/linux-Debug-x86_64/Celer/libCeler.a(Window.o): In function `Celer::Window::Window()':
/home/daniel/Documents/Development/C++/celer-engine/src/celer/Graphics/Window.cpp:6: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
/home/daniel/Documents/Development/C++/celer-engine/src/celer/Graphics/Window.cpp:11: undefined reference to `glfwDefaultWindowHints'
/home/daniel/Documents/Development/C++/celer-engine/src/celer/Graphics/Window.cpp:12: undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
/home/daniel/Documents/Development/C++/celer-engine/src/celer/Graphics/Window.cpp:19: undefined reference to `glfwSwapInterval'
../../bin/linux-Debug-x86_64/Celer/libCeler.a(Window.o): In function `Celer::Window::update()':
/home/daniel/Documents/Development/C++/celer-engine/src/celer/Graphics/Window.cpp:29: undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:78: recipe for target '../../bin/linux-Debug-x86_64/Sandbox/Sandbox' failed
make[1]: *** [../../bin/linux-Debug-x86_64/Sandbox/Sandbox] Error 1
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'Sandbox' failed
make: *** [Sandbox] Error 2
```

I know there are probably thousands of questions related to linking, but I've now spent so much time researching and I still can't get the problem.

I've setted up a GitHub repository with all of the premake and make files: [GitHub repository](https://github.com/danwolb02/celer)

This is what make executes:

```
echo "==== Building glfw (debug) ===="
make --no-print-directory -C lib/glfw -f Makefile config=debug
:
echo "==== Building Celer (debug) ===="
make --no-print-directory -C src/celer -f Makefile config=debug
:
echo "==== Building Sandbox (debug) ===="
make --no-print-directory -C test/sandbox -f Makefile config=debug
echo Linking Sandbox
g++ -o "../../bin/linux-Debug-x86_64/Sandbox/Sandbox"  ../../build/linux-Debug-x86_64/Sandbox/Sandbox.o   -L/usr/lib64 -m64 ../../bin/linux-Debug-x86_64/Celer/libCeler.a
:
```

Comment: Do you set library paths and and libraries?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Premake should do this by itself. I have a premake5.lua file in the glfw library directory and i include that into the premake5.lua file for my own project. This should keep track of the paths automatically. (It works on Windows)

Comment: It should but it looks like it doesn't. Can you provide the build command?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Sorry, there have seemed to be some problems with the repository. There should now be all files.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I use "../premake5 gmake2" and "make"

Comment: I mean the compile command. Premake creates makefiles. You are calling make on these files. Make calls gcc, clang or something else. Can you provide this line? There has to be one compile step for Celer and one compile step for Sandbox. There you can check what libraries are linked.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Sorry, I'm quite new to Linux and compiling on it. Do you mean the things gmake executes? Because I don't use any more commands. I put the make commands in the question (when useing "make -n")

Comment: This line I meant: `g++ -o "../../bin/linux-Debug-x86_64/Sandbox/Sandbox"  ../../build/linux-Debug-x86_64/Sandbox/Sandbox.o   -L/usr/lib64 -m64 ../../bin/linux-Debug-x86_64/Celer/libCeler.a`. Could you provide this line for Celer? I think you have to clean up and rebuild the project.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Oh wait... There is no line like this for Celer...

Comment: Did you try to build the project without premake? It seems like premake doesn't do what you expects. So remove it from the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I didn't catch that you using static libraries. As [Thomas Sablik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58136907/93921) said, static libraries do not include their dependencies, you need to carry those over yourself. So you need to change your Sandbox project from...

```lua
links { "Celer" }
```

To something more like...

```lua
links { 
   "glfw",
   "Xrandr",
   "Xi",
   "GLU",
   "GL",
   "X11",
   "dl",
   "pthread",
   "stdc++fs",
   "Celer"
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem, because GLFW functions aren't called inside of Sandbox. In the Window.cpp file you can see that I included GLFW before the Header file Window.hpp and the only thing included in Sandbox is Window.hpp. But even though, I already tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: @maniel34 _"I already tried this but it didn't work"_ probably because `links { "glfw", "Celer" }` is not enough. Did you read the error messages? I assume something else is missing like `dlsym`. Move all linked libraries from Celer to Sandbox and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to build the project with CMake. First I changed the current working directory to lib/glfw/build. I clean the directory with

```
rm -rf *
```

and configured and built the project with

```
cmake -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=false -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=false -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=false -DGLFW_INSTALL=false ..
cmake --build .
```

Then I created a `CMakeLists.txt` containing

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(Celer)

add_library(Celer src/celer/Graphics/Window.cpp src/celer/Debug/Logger.cpp)
target_include_directories(Celer PRIVATE lib/glfw/include)

add_executable(Sandbox test/sandbox/Sandbox.cpp)
target_include_directories(Sandbox PRIVATE src/celer)
target_link_directories(Sandbox PRIVATE lib/glfw/build/src/)
target_link_libraries(Sandbox PRIVATE Celer glfw3 dl X11 pthread)
```

in the root of your project. I changed the cwd to `build`, cleaned it up and built the project with

```
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

It worked as expected. It is necessary to link Sandbox against all the given libraries otherwise it doesn't build.

You can add the build of glfw to your project with

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(Celer)

set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES false)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS false)
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOC false)
set(GLFW_INSTALL false)
add_subdirectory(lib/glfw)

add_library(Celer src/celer/Graphics/Window.cpp src/celer/Debug/Logger.cpp)
target_include_directories(Celer PRIVATE lib/glfw/include)

add_executable(Sandbox test/sandbox/Sandbox.cpp)
target_include_directories(Sandbox PRIVATE src/celer)
target_link_directories(Sandbox PRIVATE lib/glfw/build/src/)
target_link_libraries(Sandbox PRIVATE Celer glfw3 dl X11 pthread)
```

The problem in your build configuration probably is that you try to link Celer against all dependencies but a static library can't be linked. You have to link Sandbox against the dependencies or use a dynamic library.

Comment: Ok thank you. I tried this now but with Premake and it still doesn't work. I'll see if I can do it with CMake, but I have to familiarize myself with it first. I'm asking myself if there is a difference to how this works on Windows. I already did all of this but on Windows and there it worked. The project is called Turbo, and I again have Sandbox. I do also have glfw, glad etc. as libraries. But I do only link the libraries to Turbo (lib) and not to Sandbox and it still works. I wanted to port Turbo to Linux but it's already such a mess that I tried this thing out with a new project, Celer.

Comment: I have a GitHub repository for this: https://github.com/danwolb02/turbo. Maybe there is a difference because I use Visual Studios compiler and linker?

Comment: The difference probably is dynamic and static libraries. Dynamic libraries can link other dynamic libraries. Static libraries can't.

Comment: But I use static libraries only.